# How to get the current path from an Open or Save dialog?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 20.04, I would like to get the actual path of the current folder in an Open / Save dialog:

[image]

In the example above, the path would be `/home/user/Music`.

I couldn't find a way to get it.

This is possible even in Windows, which is much less oriented for working directly with paths.

Can it be done? How?

Comment: Do you want it in text mode?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... I want to get the text `/home/user/Music`. Preferably in a textbox, but also ok to get it into the clipboard directly...

Comment: *"I want to get the text /home/user/Music"* that's what I meant.

Comment: Use Ctrl+L. See also this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154106/show-address-bar-w-full-path-in-nautilus-instead-of-breadcrumbs-bar

Comment: @FedonKadifeli ctrl+l doesn't work in dialogs.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity - is the Save dialog part of Nautilus? It seems similar to the file browser but not identical. I downloaded Nautilus' code to have a look but I don't see the Open/Save dialogs...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I don't know the specifics but I think so. Some programs have their own dialogs, for example kdenlive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps, not *exactly* what you need, but close:

Right click in a file/folder and you will have the option *Copy location*.

[image]

Comment: It's better than nothing, but I would like just the path, without the file name. I can go up one level and find the folder in the list and then do what you suggest, but it's a bit cumbersome...

Comment: @obe similarly, you could much more quickly just drag it into a terminal....

Comment: @WU-TANG it's a good tip, I didn't know that, but there are other use-cases, like copying it to another dialog (I tried and dragging doesn't work in this case). Or copying the path into a document, or pasting it in an AskUbuntu comment, etc...

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the use case.

/home/$USER is implied and can therefore be assumed.

Could you please explain what you are attempting to use the path for?

EDIT

if in the save dialogue you select the folder you are going to save the file into and do the above right click, copy location, then click through and save, the paste will have the path without the filename.

eg you have home>music which contains abba & queen (my bad taste)
navigate to home>music then right click queen > copy location
then click queen and save file as "miracle.mp3"
The "paste" will have "/home/music/queen" for you

Hope this works for you!

EDIT
paste would be ctrl-v in the editor/document of your choice (or right click menu >paste)
or shift-ctrl-v in a terminal

Comment: I just gave an example. I want to get the current path as text (e.g. to paste in the terminal). It would be best if I could also EDIT the current path as text (e.g. in order to copy the path from one dialog and paste it into another).

Comment: Essentially I want what @FedonKadifeli suggested ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154106/show-address-bar-w-full-path-in-nautilus-instead-of-breadcrumbs-bar ) - but in Open/Save dialogs.

Comment: @obe Ctrl+L in dialogs shows an *empty* box, so you can still copy there a path. If don't  already know, Ctrl+Backspace allows you to delete word by word. Very handy for this kind of situations.

Comment: never apologize for your taste in music :) the copy part works, but i'm not sure i understand the paste part..

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks! that's useful :) i wish there was a more "direct" way with less clicks (and preferably without the mouse at all...), but your tips help a lot!